# Do Admobs not work on Emulated/Test Devices in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, admob

Can someone confirm as to whether Admob ads work on emulated devices in the event that I change the appID to a live appID?

So, I had test ads appearing in my app - and then I changed the testAdUnitID with my prod Unit Ad ID, and now no ad appears in the simulator.

```
BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
  // Replace the testAdUnitId with an ad unit id from the AdMob dash.
  // https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads
  // https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads
 // adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
  adUnitId: appIDBanner,
  size: AdSize.smartBanner,
  targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
  listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
    print("BannerAd event is $event");
  },
);
```

The error I get is:

> FirebaseAdMobPlugin  adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: Request Error: No ad to show. (MobileAd  PENDING mobileAdId:277457832 for: >)
>
> flutter: BannerAd event is MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad

Is this normal and the reason it appears is because I'm on a simulator? or do I have a more urgent problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do not work on emulated devices. My production admob IDs didn't work until I actually released to production with them. I think Google wants to avoid people abusing them for money.